# SignalR completes CORS negotiation but failes hub connection with nginx proxy. Direct connection is ok, even with CORS

Tags: nginx, signalr, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have webpage at `example.com`, main api backend service at `api.example.com` and SignalR service at `signalr.example.com`.

The first and most preferred connection way is `webpage <-> main backend <-> signalr` because main backend handles other microservices in the same way and I want to keep SSL certs at one main server.

[image]

In this way SignalR completes HTTPS `/negotiate` request, but fails on all hub connection attemps.

The second connection way is parallel connections from webpage to main backend and signalr.

```
           |--> main backend
webpage <--|
           |--> signalr
```

I tested it with non-SSL connections only and it workes well.
[image]

That leads me to conclusion, that the problem is in nginx proxy config. But it looks good and pretty simple.

```
server {
// other locations and services
location ^~ /vats-hub/ {
        proxy_pass http://signalr.example.com:23166;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

For some reason, proxied signalr completes negotiation and fails only on hub connection. When I connect client directly to signalr backend - it works fine. Both cases require CORS. Differences are:

- 1st connection uses http/2, while second - http/1.1 (forcing 1st connection to use http/1.1 had no effect)
- 1st connection uses SSL, while second - does not (disabling SSL on first connection had no effect)